# How to get time if it is negative from resultset in java

Tags: java, mysql

When I run the query I get the difference as '-00:05:00'.

I am getting this exception when trying to retrieve this value through java

> java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimeFromString(ResultSet.java:6111) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getStringInternal(ResultSet.java:2137) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:2076) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:2194)

Is there a way to convert the time difference to string so that if it is negative I can retrieve it through java.

```sql
select TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(std,"%H:%i"),STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(deptime,(INSTR(deptime,":")-2)),"%H:%i")) as dep_diff from table
```

tried to retrieve with java as

```java
rs.getString("dep_diff");
```

The problem is I am taking difference of two date time fields and getting difference as dep_diff, which i'm unable to convert to string through mysql query.

Comment: Complete stack trace please

Comment: Also some code with the query could be very helpfull to us.

Comment: What is the underlying column data type in the DB.  ++ show the actual query.

Comment: Why do you have dates as strings in your database? They should be dates or timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are trying to retrieve a *duration* (which is another way to look at the time difference between two instants) as if it was a point in time relative to the Unix epoch.

Instead retrieve the string and process it with your own code, or with JodaTime, which understands the concept of a duration.

Comment: thanks for ur reply...but trying to rs.getString("dep_diff"); is giving exception.. :(

Comment: anyways now I had to work around created seperate varchar column and it works fine.... :)